# Where are the configuration files that correspond to the system settings menu stored?

Tags: 14.04, configuration, system-settings

In 14.04, I want to make a copy of my system settings (specifically my display), so that I can copy it into a virtual machine and have everything be the same every time I break and reinstall my sandbox system. All I really want to know is where are these config files located by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.  I understand and sympathize.  My solution to this problem is as follows:

1. Install a new ubuntu in the VM, with a suitable name.
2. Make a copy of the entire directory of the VM.
3. Screw around with the running VM until it breaks
4. Restore my copy of the clean vm...

Comment: The thoughts occurred to me, it seems pretty heavy-handed, but perhaps necessary. But really, I just want to know where the configuration are, not only so that I can use them, but also just for my own personal reference.

Comment: @askthewolves I believe the files to be really spread out across the system, many parts being in your home directory, and many others being in the system directories.  Additionally, the 'hardware' exposed to the VM differs slightly from the hardware in the physical machine, and there *may* be some incompatabilities.

Comment: Yeah, I'm digging into it and the whole Unity/Gnome4 interdependency structure is pretty much unnavigable. In fact I would go so far as to say Kafkaesque. I'm gonna say uncle, go with your solution and get back to work.

Comment: @askthewolves  It is brute force, but the advantage is that it works :)